# Dataset allowing Null values even when AllowDBNull = False?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, strongly-typed-dataset

I have designed a dataset using VS2008 dataset designer. In one of the datatables, I have set "AllowDBNull" property of most of the columns to be False. However, still if I create a DataRow containing null values for these columns, this datatable accepts this row, without any error.

Am I not understanding something here? Please advice. Thank you.

**Edit** Mike Spross' excellent explanation however, brings forth another question. How do we check text fields if they are System.DBNull? It is surprising that DataSets are not considering a string "" as System.DBNull and throwing an exception. Or is it not?

**Edit** I think I have found the problem and reason. I am initializing a new row of the DataTable, before filling in the values to that row. While initializing the row, default  value for string, ie, "" might be being filled in that column. I think that's it? Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The short answer is:**

`System.DBNull.Value != null`

**The longer answer is:**

In C#, the concept of a `NULL` value in SQL is represented by the `Value` property of the `System.DBNull` class. When dealing with a database, the more familiar C# `null` doesn't actually mean "null value."

When you set a database column to `null`, ADO.NET will initialize the column to whatever the default value is for that column (for example, an `int` column would be initialized to 0). That is, using `null` can actually cause a non-null value to end up in the database, and therefore you won't get an error.

If you instead set a database column to `System.DBNull.Value`, the column will actually be set to `NULL`. This is the situation that `AllowDBNulls == false` will prevent you from doing.

Comment: I had accepted this answer a while ago, but unaccepted it, just for the time being, so that answer to my further query can be provided. I will accept it, again as soon as that happens.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your "bonus" ;-) question: NULL (no string) and "" (empty string) are two different things. So it's perfectly reasonable to treat them differently. It's the distinction between null and DBNull that is messing things up. If nullable types had been available at the time of designing ADO.NET, things probably would be a lot easier. But before .NET 2.0, there was no way to represent e.g. a "null integer".

Answer (score 0):

Are you exactly assigning NULL values or an empty string to those columns? If you don't assign any value to a column, it will default to NULL (if a DEFAULT constraint is not imposed). Else you can assign a NULL value by doing -

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Col"] = null;
```

If you are assigning an Empty string to those columns, it's not equal to NULL.

And if you have a NULL value in a column which has been marked as NOT NULLABLE, it will throw an error -

> Column 'Col1' does not allow nulls.

EDIT:

By NOT NULLABLE, I mean AllowDBNull = false.

Your code seems correct. Can you try trimming the text?

Here's the whole code -

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

DataColumn column = new DataColumn("Col1");
column.AllowDBNull = false;
dt.Columns.Add(column);

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Col1"] = null;

dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: I have a text box and I am using following code:

if(this.nameTextBox.Text == "")
                    dr[DB.vinDataSet.item.nameColumn] = null;
                else
                {
                    dr[DB.vinDataSet.item.nameColumn] = this.nameTextBox.Text;
                }
But I can enter row in DataTable, even when I explicitly set the nameColumn to null.
BTW, what's "NOT NULLABLE" property. All I can see is "AllowDBNull" in the DataSet Designer.