# tableAdapter inserting NULL into not nullable fields

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dataadapter

I have read

[What is the difference between null and System.DBNull.Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value)

[INSERT / UPDATE data using DBNull or null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917921/insert-update-data-using-dbnull-or-null/7918173#7918173)

and similar Q&A but don't quite understand this.
The problem:

tableAdapter allow's me storing null into not nullable fields (`AllowDBNull = false`).

What I need to check?

I can check for

```
string.Lenght == 0
string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)
string.text = ""
```

before update command but want to know why table adapter is letting me storing `NULL`

it's actually storing someTextBox.Text = "" when needed to throw exception null not allowed for some field.

I have exactly same problem [Dataset allowing Null values even when AllowDBNull = False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788227/dataset-allowing-null-values-even-when-allowdbnull-false) but there are no solution.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have typed or untyped dataset?

Comment: @HABJAN typed dataset

Answer (score 0):

I would need more code to see for sure what you are doing, but:

```
public static object GetValue(string value) {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
    return value;
  }
  return DBNull.Value;
}
```

Would that solve your issues?

Comment: When and where to check that. I'm using auto generated (after drag and drop details from data sources) tableAdapter update command. I have textBox and if there are no text in textBox table is still being updated. TextBox is bounded to not nullable field.

Comment: When inserting data for the first time don't have that problem. Exception is thrown `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'pp_naziv', table 'winpro.dbo.pp'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.` But when editing existing record  (if I only delete text in one of the textboxes bound to not nullable field) it stores textbox.Text = "" into db.

Comment: You could make that change when your control receives data by handling the DataBinding event. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860

Comment: If the data is null, you could change it to `" "` (a single space). Do you have a way to reject the data?

Comment: I can check for string empty but it is still a string and i need null so that SQL Exception can be thrown. Why it letting me store someTextBox.Text = "" into not nullable field and how to set value to dbnull after deleting text from textbox?

Comment: An empty string is not the same as a null value.